# Let $G$ be a group of order 45. Properties of subgroups of $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a group of order 45. Then which of the following is/are true?

1. $G$ has an element of order 9.
2. $G$ has a subgroup of order 9.
3. $G$ has a normal subgroup of order 9.
4. $G$ has a normal subgroup of order 5.

Comment: If G contains an element of order 9 then G has a subgroup of order 9.

Comment: Try to show that any group of order $p^2q$ has a normal Sylow subgroup where $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Sylow theorems.

$1:$ This is not necessarily true (you might have $\mathbb{Z}_3\times\mathbb{Z}_3$).

$2:$ This is guaranteed by the first Sylow theorem.

$3:$ By the third Sylow theorem, you have $n \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ 3-Sylow subgroups. The only $n$ that satisfies this and divides the order of the group is $1$, and so it must be normal.

$4:$ Likewise, you have $n \equiv 1 \pmod 5$ 5-Sylow subgroups. Once again, the only $n$ that satisfies the divisibility criteria is $1$, and so this subgroup is normal as well.

Answer (score 1):

(2).,  (3). & (4). are always true. justification is as follows:

**justificatin for (2).**
$$3^2|45 ~\text{and}~ 3^3\nmid45$$and therefore from sylow theorem $\exists$ a subgroup of $G$ of order 9

**justificatin for (3).**

Since 5 is smallest prime divides order of group. And therefore any subgroup of $G$ of index $5$ is Normal.
and hence subgroup of index $5$ is normal.

**justificatin for (4).**

$$5|45 ~\text{and}~ 5^2\nmid45$$ and therefore from sylow theorem $\exists$ a subgroup of $G$ of order 5. Number of such subgroups will be of $1+5k$ type and $$(1+5k)~ |~9$$

$$\implies k=0$$  and hence $\exists$ unique subgroup of $G$ of order 5, and hence it would be normal.

(1) is not true for this you can take $\mathbb{Z}_3\times\mathbb{Z}_3\times\mathbb{Z}_5$